# Flutter api login using riverpod

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, riverpod

I'm trying to use riverpod for login with a laravel backend. Right now I'm just returning true or false from the repository. I've set a form that accepts email and password. The *isLoading* variable is just to show a circle indicator. I've run the code and  it works but not sure if I'm using riverpod correctly. Is there a better way to do it ?

**auth_provider.dart**

```
class Auth{
  final bool isLogin;
  Auth(this.isLogin);
}
class AuthNotifier extends StateNotifier<Auth>{
  AuthNotifier() : super(Auth(false));
  void isLogin(bool data){
    state = new Auth(data);
  }
}
final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => new AuthNotifier());
```

**auth_repository.dart**

```
class AuthRepository{
  static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/";
  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  Future<bool> login(data) async {
    try {
        Response response = await _dio.post(url+'sanctum/token',data:json.encode(data));
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**login_screen.dart**

```
void login() async{
  if(formKey.currentState.validate()){
    setState((){this.isLoading = true;});
    var data = {
      'email':this.email,
      'password':this.password,
      'device_name':'mobile_phone'
    };
    var result = await AuthRepository().login(data);
    if(result){
        context.read(authProvider).isLogin(true);
        setState((){this.isLoading = false;});
    }else
      setState((){this.isLoading = false;});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Since I'm not coming from mobile background and just recently use flutter+riverpod in my recent project, I cannot say this is the best practice. But there are some points I'd like to note:

- Use interface such `IAuthRepository` for repository. Riverpod can act as a dependency injection.

```
final authRepository = Provider<IAuthRepository>((ref) => AuthRepository());
```

- Build data to send in repository. You should separate presentation, business logic, and explicit implementation for external resource if possible.

```
  Future<bool> login(String email, String password) async {
    try {
        var data = {
          'email': email,
          'password': password,
          'device_name':'mobile_phone'
        };
        Response response = await _dio.post(url+'sanctum/token',data:json.encode(data));
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
  }
```

- Do not call repository directly from presentation/screen. You can use the provider for your logic, which call the repository

```
class AuthNotifier extends StateNotifier<Auth>{
  final ProviderReference ref;
  IAuthRepository _authRepository;

  AuthNotifier(this.ref) : super(Auth(false)) {
    _authRepository = ref.watch(authRepository);
  }

  Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
    final loginResult = await_authRepository.login(email, password);
    state = Auth(loginResult);
  }
}

final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => new AuthNotifier(ref));
```

- On screen, you can call provider's `login` method

```
login() {
  context.read(authProvider).login(this.email, this.password);
}
```

- Use Consumer or ConsumerWidget to watch the state and decide what to build.
  It also helps that instead of `Auth` with isLogin for the state, you can create some other state. At the very least, I usually create an abstract `BaseAuthState`, which derives to `AuthInitialState`, `AuthLoadingState`, `AuthLoginState`, `AuthErrorState`, etc.

```
class AuthNotifier extends StateNotifier<BaseAuthState>{
  ...
  AuthNotifier(this.ref) : super(AuthInitialState()) { ... }
  ...
}
```

```
Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
  final state = watch(authProvider.state);
  if (state is AuthLoginState) ...
  else if (state is AuthLoadingState) ...
  ...
})
```

Comment: where exactly would i place those different states?

Comment: they can be on the same class as provider if you don't want too many classes, or they can have their own class (e.g. `auth_state.dart`) for better clarity. It's up to you.

Comment: is there any reason to Do not call repository directly from presentation/screen ?

Comment: For separation of concern. Presentation calls domain/business logic, which then use infra/data/repository. Both depend on domain/business, but not with each other. It will helps in testing and manage dependencies when the app grows. 

It's more of software architecture (e.g. clean architecture, ddd, etc.) talk rather than Flutter, though. You can read more about them if you're interested.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a bool, I like to use enums or class for auth state

```
enum AuthState { initialize, authenticated, unauthenticated }
```

and for login state

```
enum LoginStatus { initialize, loading, success, failed }
```